# Firebase Firestore / React Native Chat Notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My app currently supports a chat function which is working only with Firebase Firestore, nothing else.

My idea is to implement a notification whenever a new message is received, the catch is: I want to get the notification even if the app is closed. (If you close Instagram or Whatsapp you also get notifications if somebody messages you, that's what I mean.)

The problem I face is that all Firebase listener work only as long as my app is connected to the Firebase servers but as soon as I close the app of course the app disconnects from the servers and so do the listeners not work anymore.

What I need is a function or a feature to track in the background if something on the Firebase Firestore has changed (in this case, if a new documents in a specific location was created) and if yes, trigger a notification, **even if the app is closed**.

Does anybody have an approach for me how I could accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use Firebase cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) to solve this problem as whenever there is new data available to sync it checks with the client device status and updates it. Here you can find step by step guide on [how to set it up.](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage)

Comment: Yes it was, it just took me very long to implement it but it works now. I use firebase cloud functions together with the expo-notifications package and it works briliant.